# Linq Where filtration

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Have the problem  with query result filtration.

```
public class LinkTabProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int CatalogSubSectionId { get; set; }
    public CatalogSubSection CatalogSubSection { get; set; }
}

var result = DataContext.Product                    
                .Include(o => o.Offers)
                        .ThenInclude(p => p.Prices)
                            .ThenInclude(t => t.Type)
                .Include(p => p.Brand)
                .Include(tb=>tb.LinkTabProductCategories)
                .Where( p=>p.LinkTabProductCategories **???** == id)
                .ToList();
```

I need to get products list which have: LinkTabProductCategories.CatalogSubSectionId == id

***Update*** 
This is query result List:

```
{
    "ProductId":"",
    "UID1C": "",
    "Name": "",
    "Article": "",
    "FactoryNumber": "",
    "Brand": {
        "BrandId": "",
        "UID1C": "",
        "Name": ""
    },
    "Offers": []       
    ,
    "LinkTabProductCategories": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "ProductId": 2,
            "CatalogSubSectionId": 1,
            "CatalogSubSection": null
        }
    ]
},
{},
{}.....
```

How to get  product only with "CatalogSubSectionId" == 1

Comment: What does it mean `CatalogSubSectionId( LinkTabProductCategories property )  == id`?

Comment: It mean notice that CatatalogSubSectionId IS the property of LinkTabProductCategorie,  not the method as it looks , my mistake

Comment: Use `.Where( p=>p.LinkTabProductCategories.CatalogSubSectionId  == 1)`

Comment: CS1061 C# does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is this p=>p.LinkTabProductCategories.CatalogSubSectionId giving error?

Comment: Is p.LinkTabProductCategories is list?

Comment: yes sir this is list

Comment: try `.Where( p=>p.LinkTabProductCategories.Contains(x => x.CatalogSubSectionId == 1)`

Comment: x => x.CatalogSubSectionId == 1 
----------------------------------------------
CS1660 C# Cannot convert lambda expression to type because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the condition `.Where( p=>p.LinkTabProductCategories **???** == id)` is a list, so you have to search in the list of any item whose `CatalogSubSectionId` satisfies the given condition.

You can use `Any` with this list to give the required predicate.

```
.Where(p => p.LinkTabProductCategories.Any(c => c.CatalogSubSectionId == id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method Any(predicate) — returns true, any of elements satisfies the condition predicate:

.Where(p => p.LinkTabProductCategories.Any(c => c.CatalogSubSectionId == id))